# What's the difference between archive and build?

Tags: xcode, build, archive, ipa

Generally, I'll get the ipa packet this way:
Build the project, when it's done, unfold Products directory, select the .app file and right click to choose 'Show in Finder', and the drag the file straight to iTunes, again select the app icon and right click to choose 'Show in Finder', then I get the .ipa file.
Well,there is another way to get .ipa file-*Archive*.
I'm wondering what is the difference between these two ways to get a .ipa file? Can anyone explain? Thanks advance.

Answer (score 2):

You're not able to generate dysm when you go with archive.

Build: The compilation for your source code to execute the project

Archive: As its name says, it is the overall package (.ipa) similar to .apk file (android) with that you can distribute your application.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But what is 'DYMC'? Do you mean 'dSYM'?  You mean if I just build my project, I cannot distribute it, right? Even if I configured the Code Signing properly.